# Scala: Succint way to check for null/empty values and return 0 instead

Tags: scala

I need to convert some string values to Ints after reading in a data file.  It's possible the field will be empty, which will cause an error when it tries to do the conversion.  Is there an easy way to check for null (or an appropriate value that can be converted to integer) and just return 0 if it can't be converted?  getOrElse seemed to be a possibility but I can't quite get that to work write.  I could just write a function that could do it pretty easily but I was hoping there was a more elegant/succinct way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Try` monad (documented [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.Try)), which has a `getOrElse` method:

```
import scala.util.Try
val zero = Try { "foo".toInt }.getOrElse(0)
val leet = Try { "1337".toInt }.getOrElse(0)

val parseOrZero: String => Int = x => Try(x.toInt) getOrElse 0
val lines = Seq("123", "42", "sdfd", null, "")
lines.map(parseOrZero)
->> res0: Seq[Int] = List(123, 42, 0, 0, 0)
```

Or in-line:

```
lines.map(x => Try(x.toInt) getOrElse 0)
```

`Try` also has a `toOption` method, which gets `Some(value)` if successful, or `None` on exception. So, if you wanted to filter out the bad entries instead of returning `0`, you could do:

```
lines.flatMap(x => Try(x.toInt).toOption)
```

`Try` also has all the useful monadic transformations like `map` and `flatMap` for chaining more computation.

Answer (score 1):

Convert only integer value:

```
val lines = Seq("123", "42", "sdfd", null, "")  // read strings from anywhere

val result = lines
  .filter(s => Option(s).isDefined)   // drop null values
  .filter(_.matches("\\d+"))          // drop non integer values
  .map(Integer.parseInt)              // convert to int

result: Seq[Int] = List(123, 42)
```

Or return 0 instead of incorrect:

```
val lines = Seq("123", "42", "sdfd", null, "") // read strings from anywhere

def convert(s: String): Int =
  Option(s)
    .filter(_.matches("\\d+"))
    .map(Integer.parseInt)
    .getOrElse(0)

val result = lines.map(convert)

result: Seq[Int] = List(123, 42, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The default `toInt` function throws an exception, but you can provide a safer version returning an `Option` and then use `getOrElse` on it

```
def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] =
  try {
    Some(s.toInt)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => None
  }

toInt("42").getOrElse(0) // 42
toInt("foo").getOrElse(0) // 0
```

Alternatively you can use `scalaz`, which provides a `parseInt` method on `String` which returns a `Validation[NumberFormatException, Int]`, which you can turn into an `Option`. Example:

```
"42".parseInt.toOption.getOrElse(0) // 42
"foo".parseInt.toOption.getOrElse(0) // 0
```

Comment: IMHO exception is too expensive for scala.